# Is the force of a lifting arm due to a piston an internal force?

Tags: classical-mechanics, forces

When I was analyzing an excavator, I was wondering if the force that the piston exerts on the lifting arm is an internal or external force. I am a bit confused because the geometry of the system changes when this force is exerted and this seems weird for an internal force.
[image: Example of the impact of the force on the lifting of the excavator. Don't mind the table]

Comment: But what means for you internal force, and what means external? Is *external* something coming from the environment of the excavator?

Comment: It is an external force for each body, but an inertnal force for the overall system. When you draw a FBD of the bucket you include the force at point _C_. An equal and opposite force must act on _B_ and this it is internal to the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course that's an internal force.

let's see what you are confusing about:

> I am a bit confused because the geometry of the system changes when this force is exerted and this seems weird for an internal force.

Well, you cannot tell whether a force is internal or external by whether the geometry of the system change or not.

Here's an example:

Let's say you are "floating" in outer space and feel no external force. When you raise you hand or move you head, the geometry of the system (i.e. you body) change, but the centre of mass of you body will never move until some external forces are acting on you. Otherwise, no matter how you change your posture, the centre of mass of your body will not move.